# Get node position inside hbox/vbox

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to get the X,Y postion of a TextField in the Controller Class I have wrapped in a hbox along with a Label, and ComboBox.

I know normally you can get X,Y by calling `layoutX()` and `layoutY()` but it returned 0.

Here are the fxml code

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" padding="$x1" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" spacing="10.0">
    <children>
        <Label maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="105.0" text="Add a Field:" />
        <TextField fx:id="addFieldName" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="Field Name" />
        <ComboBox fx:id="addFieldTypeComboBox" prefWidth="180.0" promptText="Choose a field type...">
          <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
              <String fx:value="Item 1" />
              <String fx:value="Item 2" />
              <String fx:value="Item 3" />
            </FXCollections>
          </items>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button fx:id="addFieldButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddFieldButtonAction" text="Add" />
    </children>
</HBox>`
```

I even tried get `addFieldName.getWidth()` and it returns 0 as well.

Comment: have you solve this problem. I am stuck on the same problem. layout, boundinparent, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are few properties of `Node` which lets you get the details of its bounds.

like `getBoundsInLocal()` and `getBoundsInParent()`;

See [getBoundsInLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getBoundsInLocal%28%29) for reference.